# MySQL Join 3 tables by 2 columns ids in the first table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables... Contacts, Outbound Operator, Digital Operator.
The contacts table contains all the contacts generated by either outbound operator and digital operator. 
So I will have these columns in "Contacts":

```
id, name, surname, id_outbound_operator, id_digital operator
```

In the second table I have all the outbound operators so the table is something like this:

```
uid, out_bound_operator_full_name
```

The third table is the same as the second but with these columns:

```
uid, digital_operator_full_name
```

I want to obtain something like this:

```
id, name, surname, outbound_operator_full_name (if this was generated by a outbound operator), digital_operator_full_name (if this was generated by a outbound operator).
```

I have to specify that in contacts table at lease one of the two

```
(id_outbound_operator/id_digital_operator) is not null
```

I tried this

```
SELECT CONTATTI.id, CONTATTI.nome_azienda, CONTATTI.telefono, CONTATTI.stato, CONTATTI.id_outbound, CONTATTI.id_digital_marketing_op, CONTATTI.blacklisted, OUTBOUND_INT_login.uid, OUTBOUND_INT_login.nome_completo, MARKETING_DIGITAL_login.uid, MARKETING_DIGITAL_login.nome_completo    
            FROM CONTATTI 
            JOIN OUTBOUND_INT_login 
            ON CONTATTI.id_outbound = OUTBOUND_INT_login.uid 
            JOIN MARKETING_DIGITAL_login
            ON CONTATTI.id_digital_marketing_op = MARKETING_DIGITAL_login.uid
```

but it doesn't work properly

Comment: You need to join with each table separately, and then combine them with `UNION`.

Comment: "it doesn't work properly" will not help us help you.  Doesn't work how?

Comment: Barman solved the question. I wrote the union even before but maybe made some other error. Now it works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `UNION` of queries that join with each of the other tables.

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.surname, o.outbound_operator_full_name
FROM CONTATTI AS c
JOIN OUTBOUND_INT_login AS o ON c.id = o.uid

UNION ALL

SELECT c.id, c.name, c.surname, m.digital_operator_full_name
FROM CONTATTI AS c
JOIN MARKETING_DIGITAL_login AS m ON c.id = m.uid
```

Comment: I used union in the first instance, but maybe I made some other errors. Now it works. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

You can join the three tables as follows. You want `left join` so that `contact` records that cannot joined with both `outbound_operator` and `digital_operator` are not eliminated from the resultset.

```
select 
    c.id, 
    c.name, 
    c.surname, 
    op.outbound_operator_full_name,
    do.digital_operator_full_name
from contact c
left join outbound_operator op on c.id_outbound_operator = op.uid
left join digital_operator do on c.id_digital_operator = do.uid
```

As commented by  Uueerdo, if you want a unique column with either the `outbound_operator_full_name` or the `digital_operator_full_name`, then:

```
select 
    c.id, 
    c.name, 
    c.surname, 
    coalesce(op.outbound_operator_full_name, do.digital_operator_full_name) operator_full_name
from contact c
left join outbound_operator op on c.id_outbound_operator = op.uid
left join digital_operator do on c.id_digital_operator = do.uid
```

The advantage of this approach is that it requires a single scan on `contact`, vs two scans when using `UNION (ALL)`.

Comment: ...and if the OP needs the name in the same result field: `IFNULL(op.outbound_operator_full_name, do.digital_operator_full_name) AS operator_full_name`

Comment: @Uueerdo: good point, I updated my answer accordingly... Thanks!